# Python - Print a line multiple times with a break after each line

Tags: python, repeat, break

I would like to print the same message multiple times, each on its own line, with a blank line in between.

This is what I'm hoping for:

```
This store is closed today

This store is closed today

This store is closed today
```

Here's what I have but without being able to figure out how to include the line break

```
print(("This store is closed today\n ") * 3)
```

Should there be a print() somewhere?

Comment: `print("This store is closed today\n\n" * 3)`

Comment: or `print('\n\n'.join(['This store is closed today']*3))`

Comment: @Guy - Sorry, new to the platform.  I like what you say but unlike 'Answers', I can't see how to respond with tick or arrow sign to show my appreciation.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. One of the more bizarre could be *print(\*(["This store is closed today"]\*3), sep="\n\n")*